# getting specific pdf page number in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a user manual for my asp.net application which I will be using as a help option for the user. I am providing help using some keywords. When users clicks or selects the keyword that he wants help with I want to open that page number of the user manuals PDF file where the keyword is there. E.G. if i search User master , then user manual should get open, directly taking me to the page where user master information is there.

Can this be done in asp.net.? C#.? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which page the keyword is on simply;

Add `"#page=4"` to the end of the link.

If you don't know the page number and you want to find the page number at run time you'll need to index the pdf document and search the document.

You can map keywords to page numbers if you know the keywords ahead of time.

Google for C# PDF searching APIs.

[dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com/) is good but it's not free.

Comment: how can I index the pdf document.? Any links that I can refer.?

Comment: Read the last 2 lines of my answer.